# How to have Factory registry macros in the beginning of header files?

Tags: c++, macros, factory, factory-method

Currently, the Factory registry macro im using is at the bottom of the header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"

class Foo : public GameObject
{
//...
};

ENGINE_SPAWNABLE(Foo);
```

This macro is functional, but is very hard to find in bigger headers and gets lost in headers with multiple classes. The macro would be best declared at the top of the class like so:

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"

ENGINE_SPAWNABLE();
class Foo : public GameObject
{
//...
};
```

But how would I go about doing this? Currently the macro only knows of the class because it's defined beforehand.

The current registry implementation is as so, only the macro part is important:

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "Object.h"

// Registers a GameObject class with the factory's registry, and connecting that to a templated SpawnGameObject function. No need to use this if the class is never spawned through the engine
#define ENGINE_SPAWNABLE(CLASSNAME) static bool CLASSNAME##Registered \
= (GameObjectFactory::GetInstance().GetGameObjectRegistry()[#CLASSNAME] = &GameObjectFactory::SpawnObject<CLASSNAME>, true)

// Singleton game object factory
class GameObjectFactory
{
public:
    // Gets instance of the simpleton
    static GameObjectFactory& GetInstance()
    {
        static GameObjectFactory Instance;
        return Instance;
    }

    // A templated function to spawn any registered GameObject
    template <typename TObject>
    static std::unique_ptr<Object> SpawnObject()
    {
        return std::make_unique<TObject>();
    }
    // A factory function that spawns an object of the specified class name
    std::shared_ptr<Object> SpawnGameObjectByName(const std::string& Name);

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<std::shared_ptr<Object>()>>& GetGameObjectRegistry(); // Returns the Registry

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Object>()>> Registry; // Registry that maps class names to factory functions
};
```

Any help or nudges towards any relevant resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your `SpawnObject()` method returns `std::unique_ptr<Object>`, and your `Registry` map stores functions that return `std::unique_ptr<Object>`, however your `GetGameObjectRegistry()` method returns a map of functions that return `std::shared_ptr<Object>`, and your `SpawnGameObjectByName()` method returns `std::shared_ptr<Object>`. So, you should fix this discrepancy.  Either you want your objects to use unique ownership or shared ownership, don't mix them.

That being said, if you want to move the macro above each class being registered, you still have to pass the class type into the macro as a parameter.  But, you can have the macro [forward-declare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) the class, eg:

```cpp
#define ENGINE_SPAWNABLE(CLASSNAME) \
class CLASSNAME; \
static bool CLASSNAME##Registered = (GameObjectFactory::GetInstance().GetGameObjectRegistry()[#CLASSNAME] = &GameObjectFactory::SpawnObject<CLASSNAME>, true)
```

```cpp
ENGINE_SPAWNABLE(Foo);
...
class Foo : public GameObject
{
//...
};
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/GpT4F0kXs)

That being said, note that your macro is declaring its `bool` in global scope as a `static` variable.  As such, every translation unit that you `#include` `Foo.h` into will get its own local copy of the `bool`.  If you want to avoid that, then you should declare the `bool` as an `extern` variable instead, and then move its definition (and thus the registration) into `Foo.cpp` instead.  Or else, you can make the `bool` be a `static` member of the `Foo` class rather than a global variable.

Comment: This is closest to what I want to get to. I wish there was a way to get rid of writing the classname. I want to have more macros like these in the future and having it just read  ENGINE_SPAWNABLE(), then ENGINE_EDITORONLY() above the class would look better but thanks.

Comment: "*I wish there was a way to get rid of writing the classname*" - then how would you expect it to discover which class name to use in the various places that need it? What if there are multiple classes being registered in the same file? The preprocessor is simply not that smart, so you have to help it - ie, pass in the class name as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Can you go with

`Spawnable.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

ENGINE_SPAWNABLE(Foo);
ENGINE_SPAWNABLE(Bar);
```

That way, all the preprocessor code gets to be in the same file and you keep the rest of your codebase clean. And because it contains only that, well, it's a the top of the file.

I'm not a fan of preprocessor hacks. But if you must do it, at least contain it somewhere manageable.

Comment: This is not possible in my case. This is clean but bad for client use, as they would have to edit engine code if they want to add new classes.